# Height can't be defined for a div with display table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I checked out if posts did already exist on this, they do, but none of them answers my questions. It only concerns `display: table-cell`...

I want to give a height of 70vh to my table, and set the `overflow` to `scroll`.

It completely ignore the height I gave to the table, and overflow does not behave like it should :

```css
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-family: 'Muli';
}

header {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    height: 100px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 2.8rem;
}

#super-table {
    display: table;
    padding: 5px;
    height: 70vh;
    overflow: scroll;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    position: relative;
}

.row div {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 0 8px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.row {
    display: table-row;
    height: 30px;
    border-width: 1px 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #CFDFE5;
}
```

```html
<div id="super-table" class="flex-col">
    <div class="table-header row">
        <div>First Name</div>
        <div>Last Name</div>
        <div>Birthdate</div>
        <div>Email</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="">Neil</div>
        <div class="">Richter</div>
        <div class="">14/08/99</div>
        <div class="">me@neilrichter.com</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="">Mohamed</div>
        <div class="">Georges</div>
        <div class="">12/05/68</div>
        <div class="">gh@ggggggAzeazeaze.azezae</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="">Denis</div>
        <div class="">Brogniart</div>
        <div class="">01/05/54</div>
        <div class="">denis.brogniart@ggggG.ggggg</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="">Jean-Mich</div>
        <div class="">Crapeau</div>
        <div class="">20/03/98</div>
        <div class="">Jean-Michclui.ilesttropfort</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="">Jean-Mich</div>
        <div class="">Crapeau</div>
        <div class="">20/03/98</div>
        <div class="">Jean-Michclui.ilesttropfort</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="">Jean-Mich</div>
        <div class="">Crapeau</div>
        <div class="">20/03/98</div>
        <div class="">Jean-Michclui.ilesttropfort</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="">Jean-Mich</div>
        <div class="">Crapeau</div>
        <div class="">20/03/98</div>
        <div class="">Jean-Michclui.ilesttropfort</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="">Jean-Mich</div>
        <div class="">Crapeau</div>
        <div class="">20/03/98</div>
        <div class="">Jean-Michclui.ilesttropfort</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="">Jean-Mich</div>
        <div class="">Crapeau</div>
        <div class="">20/03/98</div>
        <div class="">Jean-Michclui.ilesttropfort</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="">Jean-Mich</div>
        <div class="">Crapeau</div>
        <div class="">20/03/98</div>
        <div class="">Jean-Michclui.ilesttropfort</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="">Jean-Mich</div>
        <div class="">Crapeau</div>
        <div class="">20/03/98</div>
        <div class="">Jean-Michclui.ilesttropfort</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="">Jean-Mich</div>
        <div class="">Crapeau</div>
        <div class="">20/03/98</div>
        <div class="">Jean-Michclui.ilesttropfort</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="">Jean-Mich</div>
        <div class="">Crapeau</div>
        <div class="">20/03/98</div>
        <div class="">Jean-Michclui.ilesttropfort</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="">Jean-Mich</div>
        <div class="">Crapeau</div>
        <div class="">20/03/98</div>
        <div class="">Jean-Michclui.ilesttropfort</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="">Jean-Mich</div>
        <div class="">Crapeau</div>
        <div class="">20/03/98</div>
        <div class="">Jean-Michclui.ilesttropfort</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="">Jean-Mich</div>
        <div class="">Crapeau</div>
        <div class="">20/03/98</div>
        <div class="">Jean-Michclui.ilesttropfort</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="">Jean-Mich</div>
        <div class="">Crapeau</div>
        <div class="">20/03/98</div>
        <div class="">Jean-Michclui.ilesttropfort</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How do I bypass this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the *table* into another div and set the height and overflow on it.

```
<div class="scroll-helper">
  <div id="super-table">
    ...
```

---

```
.scroll-helper {
  height: 70vh;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

---

```css
.scroll-helper {
  height: 70vh;
  overflow: auto;
}

#super-table {
  display: table;
  padding: 5px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  position: relative;
}

.row div {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 0 8px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.row {
  display: table-row;
  height: 30px;
  border-width: 1px 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #CFDFE5;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll-helper">
  <div id="super-table" class="flex-col">
    <div class="table-header row">
      <div>First Name</div>
      <div>Last Name</div>
      <div>Birthdate</div>
      <div>Email</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="">Neil</div>
      <div class="">Richter</div>
      <div class="">14/08/99</div>
      <div class="">me@neilrichter.com</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="">Mohamed</div>
      <div class="">Georges</div>
      <div class="">12/05/68</div>
      <div class="">gh@ggggggAzeazeaze.azezae</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="">Denis</div>
      <div class="">Brogniart</div>
      <div class="">01/05/54</div>
      <div class="">denis.brogniart@ggggG.ggggg</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="">Jean-Mich</div>
      <div class="">Crapeau</div>
      <div class="">20/03/98</div>
      <div class="">Jean-Michclui.ilesttropfort</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="">Jean-Mich</div>
      <div class="">Crapeau</div>
      <div class="">20/03/98</div>
      <div class="">Jean-Michclui.ilesttropfort</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="">Jean-Mich</div>
      <div class="">Crapeau</div>
      <div class="">20/03/98</div>
      <div class="">Jean-Michclui.ilesttropfort</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="">Jean-Mich</div>
      <div class="">Crapeau</div>
      <div class="">20/03/98</div>
      <div class="">Jean-Michclui.ilesttropfort</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="">Jean-Mich</div>
      <div class="">Crapeau</div>
      <div class="">20/03/98</div>
      <div class="">Jean-Michclui.ilesttropfort</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="">Jean-Mich</div>
      <div class="">Crapeau</div>
      <div class="">20/03/98</div>
      <div class="">Jean-Michclui.ilesttropfort</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="">Jean-Mich</div>
      <div class="">Crapeau</div>
      <div class="">20/03/98</div>
      <div class="">Jean-Michclui.ilesttropfort</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="">Jean-Mich</div>
      <div class="">Crapeau</div>
      <div class="">20/03/98</div>
      <div class="">Jean-Michclui.ilesttropfort</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="">Jean-Mich</div>
      <div class="">Crapeau</div>
      <div class="">20/03/98</div>
      <div class="">Jean-Michclui.ilesttropfort</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="">Jean-Mich</div>
      <div class="">Crapeau</div>
      <div class="">20/03/98</div>
      <div class="">Jean-Michclui.ilesttropfort</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="">Jean-Mich</div>
      <div class="">Crapeau</div>
      <div class="">20/03/98</div>
      <div class="">Jean-Michclui.ilesttropfort</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="">Jean-Mich</div>
      <div class="">Crapeau</div>
      <div class="">20/03/98</div>
      <div class="">Jean-Michclui.ilesttropfort</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="">Jean-Mich</div>
      <div class="">Crapeau</div>
      <div class="">20/03/98</div>
      <div class="">Jean-Michclui.ilesttropfort</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="">Jean-Mich</div>
      <div class="">Crapeau</div>
      <div class="">20/03/98</div>
      <div class="">Jean-Michclui.ilesttropfort</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Alright, that kind of works, but I need to set my `.table-header` to be fixed to the top, and when I scroll, it disappears. I edited the code so you can see

Comment: @NeilRichter That's a different question, and normally Javascript is needed for that e.g. http://www.fixedheadertable.com/ a jQuery plugin.